# Can an SVG google map marker change color when it is clicked and centered?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a several grey SVG markers on a map and when each one is clicked it repositions the map so the clicked marker is in the center - all works fine. I would like to know if I can change the color of the clicked and centered marker too. This is the marker code

```
const svgMarker = {
    path: "M 12.13085 34.29385 C 2.049008 19.894699 0.177632 18.416903 0.177632 13.125 C 0.177632 5.876242 6.142236 0 13.5 0 C 20.857763 0 26.822369 5.876242 26.822369 13.125 C 26.822369 18.416903 24.950993 19.894699 14.86915 34.29385 C 14.207543 35.235428 12.792387 35.235359 12.13085 34.29385 Z",
    fillColor: "#979797",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    rotation: 0,
    scale: 1,
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(12.5, 12),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  };

   for (i = 0; i < locationsPark.length; i++) {  
    markerPark = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsPark[i][1], locationsPark[i][2]),
      map: mapPark,
      icon: svgMarker,
      label: {
        text: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerPark, "click", function () {
      mapPark.setCenter(this.getPosition()); 
      mapPark.setIcon(this.changeIcon('00ff00'));
  });
  };
```

I thought this would do it mapPark.setIcon(this.changeIcon('00ff00')); but it doesn't